# MS Access use iif statement select query as alias

Tags: ms-access-2010, iif

I am trying to build a query to get the student results for a specific exam as a table that can be merge to a word document.  The following works fine but seems very ineficient since I need to call the same query twice in the same iif statement.

```
 Test1: IIf(Round((SELECT tblMarks.Score  FROM tblMarks WHERE tblMarks.Test = 'Test1' AND [tblMarks].[ID] = [tblStudents].ID AND [tblMarks].[Rewrite] = false)*100,0)<70,70,Round((SELECT tblMarks.Score  FROM tblMarks WHERE tblMarks.Test = 'Test1' AND [tblMarks].[ID] = [tblStudents].ID AND [tblMarks].[Rewrite] = false)*100,0))
```

To get rid of the second query call I tried the following but StudentScore is not being recognized by the IIF false condition.

```
Test1: IIf(Round((SELECT tblMarks.Score  AS StudentScore FROM tblMarks WHERE tblMarks.Test = 'Test1' AND [tblMarks].[ID] = [tblStudents].ID AND [tblMarks].[Rewrite] = false)*100,0)<70,70, StudentScore)
```

I have many of those test field (test2, test3 etc...) so even just removing the extra query per field would probably help speed things up quite a bit.

Does anyone has any idea if what I am trying to do even possible???  Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I am trying to create a table/query to be use to merge into an MS Word document with fields.  This new query combines many tables into one.  Here's and example of the table structure:

tblStudent:  StudentID, Name etc... A lot of personal info.
tblScore: StudentID, Test, Score, Rewrite etc...

New Query field are:

DISTINCT tblStudent.StudentID, tblStudent.Name, tblScore.Test(as shown above) AS Test1, tblScore.Test(Same as above but with test2) AS Test2, ... Where CourseName.....

Hope this help people see what I am trying to do; which work fine I am just trying to eliminate the second query in the if statement. Sorry this is the best I can do right now since I am not at work right now and this is where all this stuff is stored.

Comment: Where are you trying to use that string? I'm having a hard time visualizing what you are doing with the rounding and embedded select's.

Comment: What happens when you test this as a new query in the Access query designer? `SELECT tblMarks.Score  FROM tblMarks WHERE tblMarks.Test = 'Test1' AND [tblMarks].[ID] = [tblStudents].ID AND [tblMarks].[Rewrite] = false`

Comment: Hi Wayne I added a little bit more info in my post to help with the understanding.  HansUp unfortunately I cannot try this right now I am not at work.  The select statement I currently use works fine I am just trying to remove the second select query in the IIF statement.  Maybe I'll post the actuall sql statement tomorrow instead of the MS Access field it might help.